# how to access Fields' (ir.model.fields) records in odoo 14?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, odoo

i am facing an issue regarding access rules in odoo 14 on  a model.
This issue occurs only on digital ocean or other service provider.
Issue error occured while accessing any model.
Error below

> You are not allowed to access 'Fields' (ir.model.fields) records.
>
> No group currently allows this operation.
>
> Contact your administrator to request access if necessary.

why this error occurs?

Comment: Is it a fresh install? Or have you changed something? Highly unlikely but check the file permissions and user on the system level as well.

Comment: What user are you logging in as? This points to an issue with [Access Rights](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/applications/general/users/access_rights.html). I would suggest you start by upgrading the `base` module. If you're having issues accessing the GUI, you could trigger this via a configuration flag or via an Odoo shell.